# disabled property on right click shows options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on MVC application. I am disabling one icon using below line. but the problem is icon got disabled.
Left click does not work on it but right click works..it shows option of "Open in new tab" which i dont want. How to disable these options ?

```
@Html.AuthorizedActionLink(" ", "Index", "PricingIncentives", new { id = item.Pricing.PricingID }, new { @class = "disabledIncentive", title = "Pricing disabled", disabled = "disabled", }
```

Comment: `disabled` is not a valid attribute of `<a>`. But why in the world are you generating a link if you don't want it to be a link? And what is `AuthorizedActionLink()` - that not part of MVC

Comment: I have customized Actionlink to AuthorizedActionLink(). i am generating it as a link beacuse it should work as a link but in ceratin conditions it should become disabled.

Comment: Again, `disabled="disabled"` is not a valid attribute of `<a>`. If you don't want the link under certain conditions, then don't render it.

Comment: I undertsand i can hide this option but any other way of doing it...

Comment: Do you mean you just want to display it as text? (then render it as a `<span>` if it meets your condition)